# Show inferred type in Intellij Scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a way to show the derived type of something in Intellij's Scala support?

For example if I am fumbling my way through some slick code and want to know what type the "user" val is perhaps by olding down a key and hovering my mouse that would be incredibly usefull.

```
    DB.withSession {
      implicit session =>
        val user = users.filter(user => user.email === email && user.password === password).first
    }
```

Any idea how to find out the type of "user" in my IDE as easily as possible?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can:

- Make sure the text cursor is within the variable and check the menu View > Type Info for its shortcut. Use that shortcut to display type info. On OS X, it's ctrl-shift-P.
- Or set preferences to show the same type info on mouse hover in Preferences > IDE Settings > Scala. Check "Show type info on mouse motion with delay" and change the delay if you want.

[image]

Alternatively, instead of just showing type info, you can show the documentation for the type. It will show the type even if there is no scaladoc or javadoc applicable.

- Use the Quick Documentation shortcut (seen in View > Quick Documentation) like the type info one. On OS X, it's ctrl-J.
- Or set preferences to show quick doc on mouse hover in Preferences > IDE Settings > Editor. Check "Show quick doc on mouse move" and change the delay if you want.

[image]

Comment: In newest IDEA the hover option is found under `Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Scala -> Editor tab`.

Comment: Any idea why this might not show anything?   When I go View->Type Info with my text cursor in a scala variable nothing happens.

Comment: Any way to change the keyboard shortcut? I want to keep it hover+Ctrl as in NetBeans (and reassign current hover+Ctrl to hover+Shift).

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @Cyäegha approach you can even tell idea to infer the type and add it for you.

On OS X, go on the variable, click alt + enter and you should see this

[image]

After you click on it you'll see

```
val test: String = "dsds"
```

The short key is at the voice *Show Intention Actions*.

Answer (score 2):

1) Select the variable or place your cursor within the variable text.

2) Press `Ctrl + Q` for `Windows/ Linux` or `F1` for `macOS`.

Answer (score 0):

Select the expression you're interested in, highlight it and use the facility that assigns it to a local variable - Cmd + Alt + V (I think, from memory) on os-x.  This will show you the type IntelliJ considers it to be.

Comment: I am not really sure what this is doing, it appears to be a command declare a val for an expression or something.  I am simply interested in finding the type of an expression.

Comment: That will show you the type that IntelliJ thinks it is. I don't know another way